# Not getting all mail accounts in android

Tags: android, email, gmail

I want to get all mails that are connected to the android device

```
Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(this).getAccounts();
accounts.length;
```

This **return 0** .. is there is something wrong ?

Comment: Have you taken the `android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS` permission

Comment: yes i have this in AndroidManifest.xml <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

Comment: And if you are testing on simulator you are sure you added the accounts?

Comment: testing on my device nexus 6p

Comment: Ok then the only thing left is are you taking this permission at runtime before you try to access the accounts

Comment: how to know that >> i just put the permission in the AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: ok so since its Nexus 6P it would definitely be Android M or above. Here you have to take runtime permissions before trying to access the accounts. See my answer below

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me,

**In your AnroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
```

**Utilities Class:**

```
public class Utilities {
      //Flag
      public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS = 200;
      /*Function to get all google accounts saved in the device.*/
      public static Account[] getAccounts(Context context) {
      //Custom exception to check if context is null
      if (context == null)
        new Throwable("Context is null!!");
      AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.get(context); 
      Account[] accounts = accountManager.getAccountsByType("com.google");
      if (accounts == null) {
        Log.d("getAccounts","Accounts is null");
        return null;
      } else {
        return accounts;
      }
   }
}
```

**Remember that android 6.0 and superiors we need that user grants permission for this actions. For this we can take the example used in the android documentation** https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html :

```
// Here, thisActivity is the current activity
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
                Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    // Should we show an explanation?
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(thisActivity,
            Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS)) {

        // Show an expanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
        // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
        // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

    } else {

        // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);

        // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
        // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
        // result of the request.
    }
}
```

**Controlling the permission response:**

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
        String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                // contacts-related task you need to do.

            } else {

                // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                // functionality that depends on this permission.
            }
            return;
        }

        // other 'case' lines to check for other
        // permissions this app might request
    }
}
```

Comment: where to get the int for the app "MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS"

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, If you change Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS for Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS, this solve this problem

Comment: MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is a constant to check if all is good, is like a flag. This variable is established in Utilities class.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed, you need to add runtime permissions for  Android M and above. To request for any permission you can use the below code and add the permissions you need. This is how you handle runtime permissions by requesting them before accessing any data related to permission

```
public  boolean isPermissionGranted() {
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {

    if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ) {
        Log.v(TAG,"Permission is granted");
        return true;
    } else {

        Log.v(TAG,"Permission is revoked");
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_ACCOUNTS}, 1);
        return false;
    }
}
else { //permission is automatically granted on sdk<23 upon installation
    Log.v(TAG,"Permission is granted");
    return true;
}
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 0:
            boolean isPerpermissionForAllGranted = false;
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && permissions.length==grantResults.length) {
                for (int i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++){
                    if (grantResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                        isPerpermissionForAllGranted=true;
                    }else{
                        isPerpermissionForAllGranted=false;
                    }
                }

                Log.e("value", "Permission Granted, Now you can use local drive .");
            } else {
                isPerpermissionForAllGranted=true;
                Log.e("value", "Permission Denied, You cannot use local drive .");
            }
            if(isPerpermissionForAllGranted){
                shoro();
            }
            break;
        }
    }
```

Once you do that, for devices with API >=23 You will get popup at runtime and then once the user accepts the permission or rejects it, your `onRequestPermissionsResult` method is called. so here you will have to handle your check whether user granted the app the permission. If yes you can continue with your logic

so call the `isPermissionGranted` method before you fetch account details in your code and if its true, run your code.

```
if(isPermissionGranted())
{
   Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(this).getAccounts();
   accounts.length;
 }
```

Comment: what if my app doesnot have activity ??